# work with single key in hash with a block

Tags: ruby

is it possible to do something like the following in Ruby?

```
hash = {:person => {:name => 'Bob', :age => 33}}
hash[:person] do |person|
    person[:name] = 'Alice'
    puts "Here, have a beer #{person[:name]}" if person[:age]> 17
end
```

What I'm trying to avoid is writing it like

```
hash[:person][:name] = 'Alice'
puts "Here, have a beer #{hash[:person][:name]}" if hash[:person][:age] > 17
```

Edit:
My first example was a bit unclear maybe. I want to be able to execute some code in the block, not just update the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at the [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) method.

```
hash = {:person => {:name => 'Bob', :age => 33}}
hash[:person].tap do |person_hash|
  person_hash[:name] = 'Alice'
  puts "Changed name"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h[:person].each do |p|
  puts p[1]
end

#=> Bob
#=> 33

h[:person].each do |p|
  puts p[0]
end

#=> name
#=> age
```